# Resolving an Integrity constraint violation error using FOSRest and Symfony

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I want to create app, witch can put some data from Angular frontend to Symfony backend via RESTful API. At this moment everything works well, but now I have some trouble. I am using FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializer.

When I trying to create new entity I get this error:

> "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Campaign (name,
>   branch) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [null, null]:SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null"

My Symfony code

```php
public function createCampaignAction(Request $request)
{
    $campaign = new Campaign();

    $form = $this->createForm(new CampaignType(), $campaign);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($campaign);
        $em->flush();

        return ['status','OK'];
    } 
    return ['status' =>  $form];
}
```

Campaign type

```php
class CampaignType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'XXX\XXX\Entity\Campaign'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'campaign';
}
}
```

And Angular

```
$scope.createCampaign = function () {
        requestData = {"campaign": {name: "itWorks"}};
        $http.post("/api/add-campaign", requestData, {
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        }).success(function (responseData) {
            console.log(responseData);
        }).error(function(responseData){
              console.log(responseData);
        });
    };
```

Looks like no data were recived, how fix it?

Comment: The error message is **Very Obvious** about what the problem is. You have passed 2 **NULL** values i.e. probably nothing to the query as parameters

Comment: Iam sending requestData = {"campaign": {name: "itWorks"}}; 
And when i dump $content = $request->getContent(); is it there as Array in array